# Unable to get style from php functions in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress plugins. I register a function and use `if` statement. Code is:

```
function custom_twitter() {
if($twitter!=''){
?>
<style type="text/css">
    .google_area {top: 40px;}
    .youtube_area {top: 80px;}
</style>
<?php } if($twitter=''){ ?>

    <style type="text/css">
        .google_area {top: 80px;}
        .youtube_area {top: 120px;}
    </style> <?php

}

}
add_action('wp_head', 'custom_twitter');
```

The function need to work like when i don't set `$twitter` value then get *first style* and when i set the value then it will get *second style*. But it doesn't work for me. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `global $twitter;` into your function or pass it as a param to the function.

Answer (score 0):

In php you compare two variables with `==` instead of `=`.

```
function custom_twitter() {
if($twitter!=''){
?>
<style type="text/css">
    .google_area {top: 40px;}
    .youtube_area {top: 80px;}
</style>
<?php } if($twitter==''){ ?>

    <style type="text/css">
        .google_area {top: 80px;}
        .youtube_area {top: 120px;}
    </style> <?php

}

}
add_action('wp_head', 'custom_twitter');
```

Comment: What exactly $twitter is ? I think the value of $twitter is NULL in your code.